# Waiting for a countdowntimer to finish

Tags: java, android, timer, countdowntimer

I need help with writing a code,

How do I make a code to wait until the countdown timer is finished?

I tried with boolean says if countdown timer is running and in the code, it was like this:

```
---part 1 of code---

While(running){}

---part2 of the code---
```

It makes the screen freeze... Idk how to solve this.. help someone?

Comment: Shouldn't you do the opposite?  Write the code you want to execute in the trigger of the countdown timer.

Comment: I need to run X times a code that include a countdown timer than changing some things an another countdown timer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CountDownTimer already has that, You just need to put the codes that you want to make them work after the timer finished, inside the onFinish(), like below

```
 countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(10000, 1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long l) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
          //this part will work after timer have finished
        }
    }.start();
```